# ODataController and the OPTIONS verb

Tags: model-view-controller, odata

I'm trying to make my WebAPI OData 4 controller handle the OPTIONS verb.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
public IHttpActionResult Options()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

But I still get a 404 on the OPTIONS request when trying to do a POST using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the current default OData routing conventions don't know how to deal with OPTIONS verb. You can create a custom `IODataRoutingConvention` to deal with that verb.

```cs
public class OptionsRoutingConvention : IODataRoutingConvention
{
    public string SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
        {
            // ...
            return "ControllerName";
        }

        return null;
    }

    public string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        if (controllerContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Options)
        {
            // ...
            return "Action";
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And then add to your configuration:

```cs
IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention> conventions =
            ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault().Concat(new[] {new  OptionsRoutingConvention()});
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "v2", builder.GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataPathHandler(), conventions);
```